# Duplicate webform entries

Tags: webforms

I have a problem with my webform. When the form is submitted, the entry is duplicated (see picture) and although I have the option to prevent duplicate entries in the module they are still duplicated. If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much.

[image][image]

Comment: What plugins/handlers do you have enabled for webform?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean but in the "Emails/handlers" section there is nothing configured at the moment

Comment: Yes, those handlers. I once had custom (and badly-written) handlers cause duplicates once, so I thought I'd look there first. I'd double check the rest of the form configuration first (both the form and the global defaults) to make sure it's not some bad combination of options. Then if that's not it, I would suggest putting breakpoints/log lines on the `preSave()` method in `webform/src/Entity/WebformSubmission.php` and see if it's being hit twice. If it does hit twice, find out where that second invocation is from. It could be from custom code or some other module you have installed.

Comment: Okay I already knew why is the problem, in the confirmation section in the confirmation type is selected as modal, this should be so, however when I select the page option it does not duplicate. The problem is that it should be a modal but without duplicating the record.